# mocking UIImagePNGRepresentation

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, uiimage, ocmock

I am trying to mock UIImagePNGRepresentation using OCMock.
UIImagePNGRepresentation accepts UIImage and returns NSData.

But it seems as you can't mock it as an ordinary function.

What I have tried is the following, but it does not compile.

```
id mockAlbumArt = [OCMockObject niceMockForClass:[UIImage class]];
id mockImageData = [OCMockObject niceMockForClass:[NSData class]];

id uiimageMock = [OCMockObject niceMockForClass:[UIImage class]];
[[[uiimageMock expect] andReturn:mockImageData] UIImagePNGRepresentation:mockAlbumArt];
```

If you look at the header for UIImage, UIImagePNGRepresentation is defined as:

```
UIKIT_EXTERN  NSData * __nullable UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage * __nonnull image);                               // return image as PNG. May return nil if image has no CGImageRef or invalid bitmap format
```

Has anyone done the mocking of the function before?  Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, ordinary functions can't be mocked that way.

Mocking libraries like OCMock and OCMockito provide a way to stub and verify method calls. UIImagePNGRepresentation isn't a method, it's a standalone C function.

So how do you replace it for testing? Don't invoke it directly, but through a function pointer. For normal use, assign UIImagePNGRepresentation to your pointer. For testing, assign a function you define.

Comment: makes sense.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Mocking C functions similar to this can be easily achieved using a Facebook library fishhook. https://github.com/facebook/fishhook

Write a alternate method in the test file:

```
NSData * __nullable swizzled_UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage * __nonnull image)
{
    return [NSData data];
}
```

and then from the test function we rebind the symbols so that our method gets called instead of the original method. kind of like method swizzling.

```
-(void)testAlbumArt
{
     rebind_symbols((struct rebinding[1]){{"UIImagePNGRepresentation", swizzled_UIImagePNGRepresentation}}, 1); 
    ....continue and expect [NSData data] when you call UIImagePNGRepresentation...
}
```